# EJS file full of Pylance errors

Tags: html, syntax-error, ejs, pylance

Yesterday everything was fine, now I come back to my code editor and it's full of Errors triggered by Pylance. I'm not sure what really happened and why Pylance works for an .ejs file but how can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Does your script still work ? (regardless of the syntax errors highlighted by your ide)

Comment: Yes it works, it's just the code editor. @EEpsylon

Comment: Apparently, Pylance is extension of your vsc, it expects to have  python file but you do provide an ejs one.
Just try to disable and i think it will be fine, i don't have an idea to be honnest why Pylance parse your file even it's marked as ejs one

Comment: Yeah disabling Pylance is one solution but I don't wanna disable it, I use Pylance for python. @EEpsylon

Comment: I opened an issue on the Pylance GitHub repo, it seems like this is a bug with a change they recently made: https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/4591

Answer (score 0):

Its a problem which the Vscode deals with automatically i don't know how but it does.The file will work as expected and 10 min later everything will become fine the errors will disappear

Answer (score 0):

Vs code will automatically solve this after some time 30 min or so, or try restarting your vs code that should do it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Disable Django extensions and restart vscode it worked for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).